# My CSS #id not working because of .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dom

I have a site that needs jquery-ui and Bootstrap selection to work with #id for modals etc, it worked wonders but then I used htaccess to hide the queries and extensions, now it is not allowing the rest of the elements that work with ids to function cause it is treating it like a page I think.

My htaccess is as follows.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^about/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ about.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^petowners/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ pet-owners.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^veterinarians/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ veterinarians.php?q=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^veterinarian/([0-9a]+)$ pet-owners.php?q=veterinarians&vID=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: A rewrite rule only affects how Apache routes the request to your backend. The hashtag for IDs should function as-is within the web browser. Since you are not performing any redirects I am inclined to suggest that you need to check your JS console for errors.

Comment: whats happening is for example i have a div with id='top' and a button floating at the bottom to make the page scroll all the way up witha href but now its treating it as a page and not going up instaed

Comment: Sounds like a JS issue/error. Check your JS console and the Network console and make sure that all of your scripts are loading and that JS is not throwing errors.

Comment: thanks very much @MonkeyZeus for the help, i managed to fix it, next time i wont post in a state of panic lol